# Jenkins - Trac ticketing automatic

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, redmine, trac

I'm working on a project.
I've got the CI Jenkins running with a GIT repo and it all works fine. When i commit a change Jenkins auto builds the project because git has changed. This is no problem.
BUT now i want Jenkins to automatically make a Trac TICKET when the build FAILS.
Haven't had much luck in googling.
Please help if you can.

Comment: I'm interested to hear what your solution is. Please post here or on the [TracMailingList](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MailingList).

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a script, like [TicketToTracScript](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TicketToTracScript), using the post build task [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) to create a task when the build fails.

Comment: Have you had success using that script with a recent version of Trac (0.12 or 1.0)?

Answer (score 2):

Use [XmlRpcPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin), an additional, sophisticated Trac API designed for such tasks.